# php mysql query updating multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql query which I am running with php like so.  Notice that the update query is updating multiple tables at the same time.

```
$sql1 = <<<TEST1
UPDATE catalog_topics a
LEFT JOIN catalog_files_join b ON a.catalogID = b.foreignKey
LEFT JOIN catalog_files_join c ON c.foreignKey = b.catalogFileID
LEFT JOIN catalog_files d ON d.catalogFileID = b.catalogFileID
LEFT JOIN catalog_lu_topics e ON a.topicID = e.topicID
SET d.catalogFileID = 'test1',
    b.catalogFileID = 'test1',
    c.foreignKey = 'test1'
WHERE b.fileTypeID = 'gvl401'
AND c.fileTypeID = 'gvl25'
AND e.parentID = 'top305'
AND a.sortorder =1
AND e.topicID = 'top312';
TEST1;
echo $sql1;
$returnVal = mysql_query($sql1);
```

I am seeing weird results if I run this query from php compared to when I run it directly in mysql.  So I am wondering if there is some other way in php to handle queries that update multiple tables at same time?

Eventhough, the above query runs fine (because $returnVal is 1) ...I dont see all the records updated in the DB.

Is there a way in php to get back the number of records that got updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_affected_rows() will return the amount of records that has been updated